# Will cold air blow if A/C Clutch doesn't engage?

Tags: honda, ac

My 2001 Honda CRV is blowing cold air in the front seat, but in the middle of the summer in the back seat, it's not very cool. If the A/C Clutch isn't engaging, will the A/C still blow somewhat cold? I don't hear it clicking on (unable to visually see it). I'd have to recheck the refrigerant levels too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. It wont cool without the clutch engaged. That is how it pumps and therefore cools the refrigerant. (someone correct me if I'm wrong) -- If you can see the belt on your engine, you should be able to see the clutch. You can tell if its engaged by looking at the disk inside the A/C compressor pully. If it rotates, its engaged.

Comment: Thanks. So I can rule out the compressor being the problem if the air *is* cool just not really cool enough? Likely needs a recharging.

Comment: @xhermit I would say LOUDLY, that it looks like you need to invest in some gauges so you can see both the high and low pressures of your refrigerant system.  And, I'd add a Chilton or Haynes service manual to your purchase list. Then you could follow the "Air Conditioning" troubleshooting guide step 1 thru X, and you'd know exactly what's going on.  (Note: there are a whole lot of things that can cause poor A/C performance.  Too much refrigerant, too little refrigerant, wrong clutch air gap, bad control valving, etc...) Get the manual, follow a systemic troubleshooting method.  Think smarter.

Comment: Yeah definitely using a manifold set and I don't go blindly charging systems unless I know what's going on.